# How to add brackets around WHERE conditions with Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using the Laravel query builder to dynamically filter data based on a user's filter selections:

```
 $query = DB::table('readings');
 foreach ($selections as $selection) {
   $query->orWhere('id', $selection);
 }
 $query->whereBetween('date', array($from, $to));
 $query->groupBy('id');
```

When I examine the SQL, I get something like this:

```
select count(*) as `count` from `readings` where `id` = 1 or id` = 2 and `date` between "2013-09-01" and "2013-09-31" group by `id`;
```

But what I need is something like this (with brackets around the or statements):

```
select count(*) as `count` from `readings` where (`id` = 1 or id` = 2) and `date` between "2013-09-01" and "2013-09-31" group by `id`;
```

How do I add brackets around WHERE conditions with Laravel query builder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved this myself by using a closure, as described in **[Parameter Grouping](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres)** in the query builder documentation.

```
 $query = DB::table('readings');
 $this->builder->orWhere(function($query) use ($selections)
 {
    foreach ($selections as $selection) {
       $query->orWhere('id', $selection);
    }
 });
 $query->whereBetween('date', array($from, $to));
 $query->groupBy('id');
```

Comment: Added alternative but I think your version my be better at handling empty results from `$selection`. Maybe they both fail if the ids are empty, I'm not sure. I guess it depends on what you want to happen if there are no ids to select. In any case, yours is the more general answer to the question in the title.

Answer (score 30):

Very useful, I use this:

```php
->where(function ($query) use ($texto){
    $query->where('UPPER(V_CODIGO)', 'LIKE', '%'.Str::upper($texto).'%')
          ->orWhere('UPPER(V_NOMBRE)', 'LIKE', '%'.Str::upper($texto).'%');
});
```

Comment: Even if the code in your answer may provide an useful solution, please use english for explanations :)

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't find this in documentation, `whereNested` was what I was looking for. Hope it helps anybody.

```
$q->whereNested(function($q) use ($nameSearch) {
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$nameSearch}%");
    $q->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', "%{$nameSearch}%");
});
```

Note: This is on Laravel 4.2

Comment: for laravel 5.1 look at the "Gonzalo Tito" answer, it looks similar and it is not documented as well, but it works and intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you may need to group several "where" clauses within parentheses in order to achieve your query's desired logical grouping. In fact, you should generally always group calls to the orWhere method in parentheses in order to avoid unexpected query behavior. To accomplish this, you may pass a closure to the where method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->where('name', '=', 'John')
           ->where(function ($query) {
               $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                     ->orWhere('title', '=', 'Admin');
           })
           ->get();
```

As you can see, passing a closure into the where method instructs the query builder to begin a constraint group. The closure will receive a query builder instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be contained within the parenthesis group. The example above will produce the following SQL:

```
select * from users where name = 'John' and (votes > 100 or title = 'Admin')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WHERE IN` here for the same effect:

```
$query = DB::table('readings');
$query->whereIn('id', $selection)
$query->whereBetween('date', array($from, $to));
$query->groupBy('id');
```