# Laravel nested or with and in where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

My Expected query is

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `books` 
where (`books`.`is_deleted` = 0) 
and `category_id` = '61' 
and (`title` like '%問いかけの作法 チームの魅力と才能を引き出す技術%' or `title` like '%問イカケノ作法 チームノ魅力ト才能ヲ引キ出ス技術%' or `title` like '%問いかけの作法 ちーむの魅力と才能を引き出す技術%');
```

I have written my conditions like below ways

```
        $queryCondition = $this::where(['books.is_deleted' => false]);

        if( isset($queryString['category']) ){
            $queryCondition->where('category_id',$queryString['category']);
        }

        if( isset($queryString['searchKey']) ){
            $search = mb_convert_kana($queryString['searchKey'],"rns");
            $kana = mb_convert_kana($search,"KVC");
            $katakana = mb_convert_kana($search,"KVc");

            $queryCondition->where('title','like','%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('title','like','%'.$kana.'%')
                ->orWhere('title','like','%'.$katakana.'%')
            ;

        }
```

I'm getting the output query like below

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `books` 
    where (`books`.`is_deleted` = 0) 
    and `category_id` = '61' 
    and `title` like '%問いかけの作法 チームの魅力と才能を引き出す技術%' or `title` like '%問イカケノ作法 チームノ魅力ト才能ヲ引キ出ス技術%' or `title` like '%問いかけの作法 ちーむの魅力と才能を引き出す技術%';
```

Without the () in last condition. How can I fix it ? Without this way has there any other ways to implement nested or in laravel ? Example

```
$query->where([
                'OR' => [
                    [name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'],
                    [search LIKE' => '%'.$kana.'%'],
                    [search LIKE' => '%'.$katakana.'%']
            ]
]);
```

Comment: Maybe wrapping your query condition with a where(function ($query) { $query->where... }) could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694866/how-to-add-brackets-around-where-conditions-with-laravel-query-builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('title','like','%問いかけの作法 チームの魅力と才能を引き出す技術%')
        ->orWhere('title','like','%問イカケノ作法 チームノ魅力ト才能ヲ引キ出ス技術%')
        ->orWhere('title','like','%問いかけの作法 ちーむの魅力と才能を引き出す技術%');
})
->get();
```

The closure will give you the `()` that you are seeking for.

[**Laravel documentation 9.x**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses) itself asks to add orwhere via above.

> You should always group orWhere calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.

*From docs:*

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('votes', '>', 100)
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'Abigail')
                      ->where('votes', '>', 50);
            })
            ->get();
```

which will give you,

```
select * from users where votes > 100 or (name = 'Abigail' and votes > 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try **whereRaw** with raw query instead of **orWhere**

So, instead of this

```
->orWhere('title','like','%'.$kana.'%')
->orWhere('title','like','%'.$katakana.'%');
```

Do this

```
->whereRaw('title LIKE "%$kana%" OR title LIKE "%$katakana%" ');
```

From my experience, anytime i use **orWhere()**, it ignores all other conditions so i prefer to use **whereRaw**  and it works fine for me without any issues

Comment: You need to group the `orWhere()` in order to build the query. Otherwise you will get undesired results.